# How to scroll my chat plugin to bottom with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready((function() {
    load_data = {
        'fetch': 1
    };
    window.setInterval((function() {
        $.post('shout', load_data, (function(data) {
            var old_data = $(".message_box")
                .html();
            if (old_data != data) {
               $(".message_box").html(data);
                // get scrollHeight
                var scrollHeight = $(".message_box").get(0).scrollHeight,
                    // get current scroll position
                    scrollTop = $(".message_box").scrollTop(),
                    // calculate current scroll percentage
                    percentage = Math.round(
                        (100 / scrollHeight) *scrollTop);
                var scrolltoh = $('.message_box')[0].scrollHeight;
                $('.message_box').scrollTop(scrolltoh);
                // make sure user is not scrolled to top
                if (percentage > 0.0001) {
                    $(".message_box").scrollTop(scrollTop);
                }
            }
        }));
    }), 5000);
```

Why my chat script won't go till end? So when I load my page can't see last message without scrolling (only 2nd last is showing, otherwise code is working).

Bonus: How to stop scrollbars blinking? Now it's in loop so if I scroll my chat, scrollbar is blinking always after 5 seconds.

Comment: See this simple post: http://jsfiddle.net/jPVAf/50/